# ANDROID 4 KITKAT Code push is successful but the app doesn't update

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Code push is successful.

When opened, the app does not update. Trying to log it produces the error ***UNKNOWN_ERROR*** from codepush sync.

**Expected Behavior:**

Code push should update the app after the user closes the App and restarts it manually. Only then should the update show up in the App.

**Actual Behavior**

Nothing happens and the app doesn't update. When I use it on splash screen, attempting to load it doesn't work as it gets stuck.

**Reproducible Demo**

[This is my repo](https://github.com/Rezaramdhanisti/codepush) in case you need it

Just codepush and restart the apps on Android 4 (Kitkat)
Environment

I have tried two environments.

react-native-code-push version: 5.3.2 and newest version

react-native version: 0.57.2 and newest version

iOS/Android/Windows version: Android Kitkat

Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build ? Release build

Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device? Both?